# Apache2 Name-Based VirtualHosts and SSL

Tags: ssl, encryption, https, debian, apache2

I am having problems with **Apache2**. I need to configure different **SSL certs**: one for each site. This is my configuration *(virtual hosts name-based)*:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
  #other stuff...
  ServerName Site1
  ServerAlias   site1.com
  DocumentRoot  [...]/site1
  SSLCertificateFile cert1.pem
  SSLCertificateKeyFile key1.key
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
  #still other stuff...
  ServerName Site2
  ServerAlias   site2.com
  DocumentRoot  [...]/site2
  SSLCertificateFile cert2.pem
  SSLCertificateKeyFile key2.key
</VirtualHost>
```

So if I access **site2.com** I should be encrypted with the certificate "**cert2**". For some reason, Apache2 will transmit "**cert1**" instead. Anyway, the directory which I am redirected to is correct: `[...]/site1` for **site1** and `[...]/site2` for **site2**.

So the problem is only about SSL certificates, and **not** directories.

Hope someone can help.

Comment: Don't you need a `ServerName` directive in each virtual host?

Comment: You're right, thanks @PresidentJamesK.Polk ... but in my real configuration there is. I only missed here in Stack Overflow. Just updated my question.